# Is it possible to get and display the linkedin user id?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I don't understand is it possible or not to get the linkedin user id. Because in docs I see this

> The unique identifier for the given member. May also be referenced as the personId within a Person URN (urn:li:person:{personId}). The id is unique to your specific developer application. Any attempts to use the id with other developer applications will not succeed.

I need this to display on my website after user sing up with linkedin button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with linkedin api but based on description you quoted it's same as facebook api V2+. Basically when a user signs up to your website by LinkedIn, a new user id is generated specifically for this user-app relationship. If user visits your website again retriving their information from linkedin would show you same user id. But if same user grants permissions to another app (signs up in another app) with his/her linkedin account, the second app is going to see a different userid than the one you see.

The user id you are receiving should be enough for almost all legit cases unless you have multiple apps registered in linkedin and need to track users between them which in that case you can use  fields like email or others(i don't know what linkeddin offers)

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer. In general, you can't get the ID that is listed in the link to the user's profile https://www.linkedin.com/in/USER_PROFILE_ID, right?

Comment: @ViktorLegon no, because it's the original id that apps cant access.
all these changes happened after Cambridge Analytica scandal to prevent apps tracking users beyond the scope of their service.